# Automatic logins in chrome

Tags: authentication, google-chrome, http-authentication

I have an outdated internal website (which I cannot alter), which uses one of those old login mechanisms which pops up a modal authentication box when you try to access it.
(The popup is not HTML, but rather a browser implemented box)

As this site is a dashboard that boots up when the PC starts, I would like to be able to login to this site unattended. The problem is that while chrome can save the password for this site, it still requires you to press the "login" button after it autofills the fields.

This computer does not regularly have a mouse/keyboard connected, so that is no good for me.

Is there someway to configure chrome to just log in without waiting for the user to press "Log In"?

If not, than like I said, I cannot access the server, but I could install any type of proxy/bot on the client computer. This site isn't very sophisticated, so it should be trivial to "hack" (although I really prefer a chrome based solution)

[image]

Comment: Did you try a [web search](https://www.startpage.com/do/dsearch?query=chrome+http+basic+auth+login+box&cat=web&pl=opensearch&language=english)? The first result I get is a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/multipass-for-http-basic/enhldmjbphoeibbpdhmjkchohnidgnah?hl=en) that neatly solves the problem.

Comment: Usually the first part involves using curl (especially with options -b and -c ) and retrieving a session cookie. The second part is about converting curl's cookie into chrome's native format using sqlite3.

Comment: @Michael Hampton that does the trick. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?